# AutoMapper ProjectTo ignoring .Include

Tags: .net, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm learning Automapper, and EF Core, and stumbled onto a problem, while trying to model get-only property, which is calculated based on navigation property.
I'm having two models:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Childs {get;set;}
    public int WantedChildCount {get{return Childs?.Count(c=>c.Type!=1)??0;}
}
public class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Type {get;set;}
}
```

One DTO:

```
public class VM
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int WantedCount{get;set;}
}
```

And trying to automap VM from Parent like:

```
var c = context.Parents.Include(p => p.Childs).ProjectTo<VM>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Automapper configured like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg=>
    cfg.CreateMap<Parent, VM>()
    .ForMember(d=>d.WantedCount, o => o.MapFrom(s=>s.WantedChildCount));
```

The problem is that in resulting VM field WantedCount isn't populated. In logs I've found message

```
The Include operation for navigation: 'p.Childs' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results.
```

It's easy so split this operation into two separate: first take Parent, and then Mapper.Map. 
Also, it could work when changing Map like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Parent, VM>()
    .ForMember(d=>d.WantedCount, o => o.MapFrom(s=>s.Childs(c=>c.Type!=1));
```

But this way I'll ignore get-only property in model totally.
I'd like to understand what the problem is, and how could I solve it.

Or maybe I should even somehow move calculation to DB side? But I'd like to avoid storing this property in database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ProjectTo` is the Auto Mapper equivalent of `Queryable.Select`, hence the resulting query fall into EF Core [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) category.

As usual with `IQuerable<T>` queries, you should use explicit *expression* which can be mapped to SQL, e.g. something like this accessiong directly the navigation property

```
o.MapFrom(s => s.Childs.Count(c => c.Type != 1))
```

Note that while this should populate the desired `WantedChildCount`, the `Include` will still be ignored.

Comment: Well, that's sad. I wanted to get mapping in DB layer, guess I'll refactor my *Count property to be calculated on DB side somehow.

Thanks, I'm accepting your answer, because it's correct, and I've been reading about it earlier. I asked a question trying to find alternative...